# How come duplicate questions show up in the sidebar?

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

In [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22215/adding-words-to-dfa-maintaining-minimality) question the "Related" sidebar contains [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18278/maximum-number-of-states-in-minimized-dfa-from-nfa-with-n-states?rq=1). But that question was marked (rightly so) as duplicate on November 28, 2013 (3 months ago, so there isn't the excuse that it was selected before being deemed duplicate). If we want to weed out duplicate/redundant questions, this shouldn't happen. I often look up the related questions, and sometimes had comments or supplementary answers for them, which are closed for duplicates AFAIU.

Or is there a rationale for this I don't see?

Comment: I suspect that the answer is simply because the related question search algorithm works only on the question's text, not its closure status. I'll point SE staff to this question.

Comment: Somewhat related, and currently unanswered: [Why doesn't the Related question list show that questions are closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126460/why-doesnt-the-related-question-list-show-that-questions-are-closed); [Related Questions Include Closed Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/related-questions-include-closed-questions)